# How to make a custom view in an App Widget similar to the one in Google Play Music widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've just found out of the Google Play Music widget "What's this song?" and I was very surprised to find this custom view in it:

[image]

How does this happen? As far as I know, you can't have custom views in `RemoteViews`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I know and it's just pretty simple. It must be a simple ImageView that gets updated every 400ms or so with a generated bitmap showing the wave. There is no animation between the frames so I think it's just a matter of drawing stuff on a canvas or generating a more advanced bitmap in the NDK layer. Interesting!